# QFile error : device not open

Tags: qt, qfile

I have a code:

```
int actualSize = 8;
QFile tableFile("C:\\Users\\Ms\\Documents\\L3\\table"+QString::number(actualSize)+".txt");
QTextStream in(&tableFile);
QString oneLine;
oneLine.append(in.readAll());
if(tableFile.exists())
{
    messageLabel->setText(oneLine);
}else
{
    messageLabel->setText("Not open");
}
```

In the `C:\Users\Ms\Documents\L3\` folder, I have a "table8.txt" file. But the `messageLabel` (which is a QLabel) will have a "Not open" text, `oneLine` is empty, `tableFile.exists()` is false, and I got a device not open warning/error.

I tried relative path, like

```
QFile tableFile("table"+QString::number(actualSize)+".txt");
```

But none of the methods I come up with was good.

Comment: and where is invocation of `open` method?

Comment: tableFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
I added this line and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `/` separators for all QFile-related paths. **Open** the **file** before you read it and **close** it when done.

```
int actualSize = 8;
QFile tableFile("C:/Users/Ms/Documents/L3/table"+QString::number(actualSize)+".txt");
if(tableFile.exists() && tableFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    QTextStream in(&tableFile);
    QString oneLine;
    oneLine.append(in.readAll());
    messageLabel->setText(oneLine);
    tableFile.close();
} else
{
    messageLabel->setText("Not open");
}
```